# Convert log string into regex for fail2ban

Tags: regex, security, terminal, vnc, fail2ban

I'm having trouble in converting a log string related to a VNC server and client interaction, so that I can ban certain IPs with the use of fail2ban.

The problematic string in the logs of the VNC is the following:

```
** (vino-server:28986): WARNING **: 01:02:54.300: VNC authentication failure from '888.88.9.999.dynamic.whatever.net'
```

That is the exact string I need to match (with all the parenthesis, asterisks...), with obviously telling the **fail2ban** following command where the host is.

**WHAT I HAVE TRIED SO FAR:**

**Command to do checks:** `fail2ban-regex "log line" "failregex"`

---

```
fail2ban-regex "00:19:51.297: VNC authentication failure from 'server-185-153-197-251.cloudedic.net'" "VNC authentication failure from '<HOST>'"
```

It works; but the log line string is not the same as in the logs.

When using the exact log line, I fail constantly:

```
fail2ban-regex "** (vino-server:11241): WARNING **: 00:19:51.297: VNC authentication failure from 'server-185-153-197-251.cloudedic.net'" "authentication failure from '<HOST>'"
```

- Is it something related to not understanding how the failregex expression should be put?
- Is it something associated with having special characters within the log file?
- Is it any error that I have made with the strings?

If you could help me to go in the right direction I would appreaciate it so much, so that I can get to understand more about regex and be able to secure the systems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has basically nothing with regex, more it is fail2ban thing - to avoid confusion with expected data, several of its default datepattern's are "anchored" to begin of line (especially simplest time, like your format), so you've to specify your own `datepattern` for that.

This should work for you:

```sh
msg="** (vino-server:11241): WARNING **: 00:19:51.297: VNC authentication failure from 'server-185-153-197-251.cloudedic.net'"
fail2ban-regex -d '\s%H:%M:%S\.%f:' "$msg" "authentication failure from '<HOST>'"
```

Note that fail2ban will cut out the part of message matching `datepattern` before `failregex` search would start, so ahead anchored `failregex` for your log-excerpt looks like:

```
fail2ban-regex -d '\s%H:%M:%S\.%f:' "$msg" "^\*\* \(\S+\): WARNING \*\*: VNC authentication failure from '<HOST>'"
```

Also note that in fail2ban config files you've to specify `%`-char using `%%`, so it'd look like this:

```
datepattern = \s%%H:%%M:%%S\.%%f:
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much for taking the time; it works perfectly. I have found to set the datepattern in the jail file, together with the other options. One last question: as both of the options you mentioned work, ¿is it advisable to use the more complete pattern instead of the shorter one? I'm thinking in terms of latency of matching, but I may be not seeing something else.

Comment: It is advisable to use anchored RE (at least from one side), no matter short or long.

Comment: Another little question: I'm finding some issues to match other hosts like 'd303-nl2.freeflux.org'. Is there any way to match all the hosts that are inside those '', independently of their structure? With just the <HOST> coding is not sufficient. Thanks again!

Comment: WARNING: Unable to find a corresponding IP address for d303-nl2.freeflux.org: [Errno -2] Name or service not known

Comment: The issue is well known, the `<HOST>` would match, but it can not resolve to IP (if domain does not have a reverse PTR entry), then you'll see something like following in log:
WARNING: Unable to find a corresponding IP address for d303-nl2.freeflux.org: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
You can also check it with fail2ban-regex -l WARNING ...

And it is almost unsolvable (unless own DNS server used to cache forward IP->DOMAIN, as reverse PTR DOMAIN->IP).
Better would be to configure your VNC to log IP instead of hostname.

Comment: Okey, understood the issue. Thanks for the insights. Could you please point me out or give some more information on how to log the IP directly with the vino-server if you know the approximate process? I remember that I didn't find resources at the time I researched this.

Comment: I have no idea how (or whether) it is configurable by vino. If you don't find this in man's, either use other vnc logging properly; or use it over ssh tunnel only; or reject new connects to the port per default and allow it for known IPs only, e.g. using url knocking (fail2ban's pass2allow or similar thing) or per port knocking. there are many strategies possible.

Comment: Okey, many thanks. As it is used via my mobile phone I was not able to set up the ssh tunnel approach, so I think I will use the iptables approach to restrict the connections to the port to just the known ones (it is not the best one because at the end of the day I want to be able to access as a last resort from anywhere, and most of the times you are behind some other router, IP or network, even with 4g). Do you have any of the approaches that could suit better? Actually I have a complex password set up, but the issue is that others ping and try to connect constantly.